# compare value from HashMap with a String

Tags: java, hashmap

```
    String keys = "3|PNSN--G";   
    System.out.println(keys);
    System.out.println(test.get(keys));
    if ("c"==test.get(keys))
        System.out.println("Sucess");
    else
        System.out.println("Failed");



    3|PNSN--G
    c
    Failed
```

Why i cant compare it? If "c" is a String and value is a String "c" why it fails?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520432/java-vs-equals-confusion

Comment: `==` checks if both strings are stored at the same place in yuor computrs memory. `equals` checks if they have the same value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `.equals()` rather than `==` operator for comparing String contents. `==` operator will check if both references point to same Object instance or not which is clearly not the case here.

Answer (score 0):

String comparison in Java is just a comparison of the references.

You should use `"c".equals(test.get(keys))`.